# VS 2017 and editor suggestions

Tags: visual-studio, acumatica

I recently downloaded VS 2017 and it has a lot of suggestions stating naming rule violations that appear for the methods related to actions and in the DAC definitions to name a few.  Does anyone have suggestions for editor settings that work best with Acumatica so that meaningful suggestions are shown, but those that are violated intentionally due to the framework can be suppressed?

Answer (score 0):

Select menu Tools->Options
In the left pane tree view, select item Text Editor->C#->Code Style->Naming

If the Suggestion bothers you, you can change the Severity field from Suggestion to Refactoring Only:
[image]